# C# PropertyInfo SetValue and Array

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

```
int size = Convert.ToInt32(sizeAttribute.Value);
Array newArray =  Array.CreateInstance(fieldType.GetElementType(), size);
PropertyInfo info = component.GetType().GetProperty(fieldNameAttribute.Value, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
var r = Convert.ChangeType(newArray, fieldType);
info.SetValue(component, r);
```

is there a way to let the array be filled with nulls.

Right now the line `info.SetValue(component, r);` is returning this error :

> {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `component` isn't null or it would fail two lines before that. So more likely `info` is null, meaning it didn't find the property you're looking for. If you still have trouble after fixing that then we might need to see the property you're trying to set.

Comment: Target invocation Exception meaning that the SetValue is being invoked, meaning info is set properly

Comment: its an array the type is a class

Comment: I can Add Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType.GetElementType()); and the error goes away. But I want the array to be filled with nulls

Comment: But Reflection won't let me set the value if the array has any null value.

Comment: Did you step through this with a debugger? Thereby you could see _what_ has been `null`. Does the targetted property have a setter that throws this exception if the given value is null? Then I suspect that `r` is `null` if `ChangeType` failed. I can't see why you need `ChangeType` anyway.

Comment: yes I steped through with the debugger. The Code works fine if i assign the array values, but I want the array to be filled with nulls

Comment: the Code works fine if I add

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
newArray.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(fieldType.GetElementType()), i);

but i want the array filled with nulls

Comment: Ah ok, so it seems it has nothing to do with your code, but it's probably the `component` that throws the exception. Do you have access to the code of the target types you are handling here?

Comment: Can you show the property you're trying to set? The question isn't complete without that.

Comment: the property is an array of a class named Burst

Comment: Sorry, Problem solved